# Selenium 2.20: how to handle User Identification Request dialog

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

i'm new to Selenium, but have some simple website automation working.
here's what i cannot figure out: i have a website that uses user
certificates to validate users. i issue the following...

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://xt01:9100/owf/");
```

when the website comes up, so does the User Idenification Request
dialog asking which cert i want to "login" using. i am unable to get
hold of that dialog to specify the cert and to hit the  button,
therefore the first screen that shows up is a "not authorized" screen
(since i didn't specify either 1) any cert or 2) the right cert)

Q) how am i supposed to "grab" this dialog? Selenium IDE doesn't register the dialog (doesn't seem to "see" it, therefore doesn't include any clicks in it)

there is an option (Tools-Options-Advanced-Encryption) that sez: "When
a server requests my personal certificate" with the choices being
"Select one automatically" or "Ask me every time". on the Firefox
instance that starts up, i set it to "Select one automatically" and
click , however this is not "remembered" on the next start-up (it
is reset to "Ask me every time"), therefore i need to be able to
capture the User Identification Request dialog and process it BEFORE
beginning my test....How?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5):

Certificate prompting can be specified in your profile's `prefs.js` via `user_pref("security.default_personal_cert", "Select Automatically");` 
Using Firefox 33.0 and selenium-webdriver-2.47.1 worked for me.

Comment: Thanks !! Worked for me with Mozilla Firefox 52.0.2 and geckodriver 0.16.1

Comment: Works in FF 101.0 as well

Answer (score 2):

So far I did not have time to try it, but I think it should help:

- Create new Firefox profile and name it something familiar - e.g. `selenium`
- In this profile, install given certificate and let FF remember your decission
- When creating new instance of FireFoxDriver, try this:

  ```
  ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
  FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("selenium");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
  driver.get("https://xt01:9100/owf/");
  ```

Comment: This worked! took me awhile to create a profile (as i had never done this before). thanks!!

Comment: Firefox 23.0.1 will ask you to choose the certificate, even if you select to remember decision (and have only 1 option in the list). :(

Comment: (I mean after you restart the browser) 
Any workaround for this?

Comment: As stated - not yet tried by myself. That approach was somewhat working, but it does not again. My solution was - I clearly stated to management that if they want test automation, they have to provide me environment without certificate ... and they did ;)

Comment: To create a profile in firefox, in the url bar enter about:profiles and firefox will display the "About Profiles" page. From there you can create new profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are managed by the OS, not the browser. Delete all but the necessary certificate from your browser's certificate store and then configure the browser to automatically select the certificate when only one certificate is present. You could also create a browser profile and have your program launch this profile or avoid testing over HTTPS.